# Need to extract following texts which doesn't have a clear xpath with rvest in R

Tags: html, r, xml, web-scraping, rvest

I have a few webpages which I wanted to scrape (html example below). In my example I wanted to get the company name, location, salary, posted date so my approach to get the company name is like this:

```r
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

url <- "https://joblist.ala.org/job/library-director/53812381/"
page <- xml2::read_html(url)

company_name <- page %>% 
  rvest::html_nodes("li") %>%
  rvest::html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@class="clearfix"]') %>%
  #rvest::html_nodes("div")%>%
  rvest::html_nodes("span") %>%
  #rvest::html_name()%>%
  rvest::html_text()%>%
  stringr::str_replace_all("[\r\n\t]" , "")%>%
  stringr::str_trim()
```

However this yields:

```r
# [1] "Description"                                                    
# [2] "We are looking for a Skilled, Dynamic, and Collaborative Leader"
# [3] "Mobile Public Library"                                          
# [4] ""                                                               
# [5] "Mobile, Alabama, United States"                                 
# [6] "53812381"                                                       
# [7] "April 21, 2020"                                                 
# [8] "Library Director"                                               
# [9] "Mobile Public Library"                                          
# [10] "Public Library"                                                 
# [11] "Administration/Management"                                      
# [12] "No"                                                             
# [13] "Full-Time"                                                      
# [14] "Indefinite"                                                     
# [15] "Master's Degree"                                                
# [16] "5-7 Years"                                                      
# [17] "0-10%"                                                          
# [18] "Jobs You May Like"
```

I thought I can get what I want through indexing, but then when I move to next site, the position for some elements change. Like here:

```r
url <- "https://joblist.ala.org/job/ceo-library-director-orange-county-library-system/53673222/"
page <- xml2::read_html(url)

company_name <- page %>% 
  rvest::html_nodes("li") %>%
  rvest::html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@class="clearfix"]') %>%
  #rvest::html_nodes("div")%>%
  rvest::html_nodes("span") %>%
  #rvest::html_name()%>%
  rvest::html_text()%>%
  stringr::str_replace_all("[\r\n\t]" , "")%>%
  stringr::str_trim()
```

Yields:

```r
# [1] "Description"                                           
# [2] "Requirements"                                          
# [3] "Orange County Library System"                          
# [4] ""                                                      
# [5] "Orlando, Florida, 32801, United States"                
# [6] "53673222"                                              
# [7] "April 1, 2020"                                         
# [8] "CEO / Library Director -  Orange County Library System"
# [9] "Orange County Library System"                          
# [10] "Public Library"                                        
# [11] "Administration/Management"                             
# [12] "No"                                                    
# [13] "Full-time"                                             
# [14] "Indefinite"                                            
# [15] "Master's Degree"                                       
# [16] "Over 10 Years"                                         
# [17] "10-25%"                                                
# [18] "$151,882.00 - $160,000.00 (Yearly Salary)"             
# [19] "Jobs You May Like"
```

Console Inspector looks like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li class="clearfix">
  <div>Location: </div>
  <span class="">

  Orlando, Florida, 32801, United States 

  </span>
  </li>

  <li class="clearfix">
  <div>Job ID: </div>
  <span class="">53673222</span>
  </li>                           
  <li class="clearfix">
  <div>Posted: </div>
  <span class="">April 1, 2020</span>
  </li>


  <li class="clearfix">
  <div>Position Title: </div>
  <span class="">CEO / Library Director -  Orange County Library System</span>
  </li>

  <li class="clearfix">
  <div>Company Name: </div>
  <span class="">Orange County Library System</span>
  </li>

  <li class="clearfix">
  <div>Library or Company Type: </div>
  <span class="">Public Library</span>
  </li>

  <li class="clearfix">
  <div>Job Category: </div>
  <span class="">Administration/Management</span>
  </li>

  <li class="clearfix">
  <div>Entry Level: </div>
  <span class="">No</span>
  </li>

  <li class="clearfix">

  <div>Job Type: </div>
  <span class="break-all">Full-time</span>
  </li>

  <li class="clearfix">

  <div>Job Duration: </div>
  <span class="break-all">Indefinite</span>
  </li>

  <li class="clearfix">

  <div>Min Education: </div>
  <span class="break-all">Master's Degree</span>
  </li>

   <li class="clearfix">

   <div>Min Experience: </div>
   <span class="break-all">Over 10 Years</span>
   </li>

   <li class="clearfix">

   <div>Required Travel: </div>
   <span class="break-all">10-25%</span>
   </li>

   <li class="clearfix">

   <div>Salary: </div>
   <span class="break-all">$151,882.00 - $160,000.00 (Yearly Salary)</span>
   </li>


</ul>
```

I was wondering if someone can help me out by showing how to get the company name, I can replicate it for others. Not good with HTML. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are no specific classes for each category, we may use regex to extract the information.

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://joblist.ala.org/job/library-director/53812381/"
page <- xml2::read_html(URL)

page %>% 
  html_nodes("li") %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@class="clearfix"]') %>%
  html_text() %>%
  gsub('[\r\n\t]', '', .) %>%
  grep('Company Name:', ., value = TRUE) %>%
  sub('Company Name:', '', .) %>% .[2]

#[1] " Mobile Public Library"
```

You can extract the information from other categories in the same way. For example, with `'Position Title:'` :

```
page %>% 
  html_nodes("li") %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@class="clearfix"]') %>%
  html_text() %>%
  gsub('[\r\n\t]', '', .) %>%
  grep('Position Title:', ., value = TRUE) %>%
  sub('Position Title:', '', .) %>% .[2]

#[1] " Library Director"
```

Probably, you could just write a function and pass strings like `"Company Name:"` and `"Position Title:"` to it.

Comment: Thanks you Ronak. Due to time difference, I couldn't reply in a quick manner sorry about that. This works!